# Balkan Olympiad in Mathematics 2001

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving

Where can I find the solutions of the problems from the Balkan Olympiad in Mathematics 2001, Belgrade?

Comment: I think this is not the right place to ask such question. I have no idea to propose you another sites that may suitable to ask for such solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to find solutions (or at least hints) on [this site](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4073_2001_balkan_mo) (click on "View topic" on the right-hand side to view discussion and solutions of the specific problems).

This is how I found it:

- I entered `balkan mathematics olympiad 2001 solutions`into google.
- I checked every result. The ninth one led me (after some clicking) to the above link.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me!